# Converting Minutes Column to Days, Hours and Minutes SQL

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a column like this -

```
XXX_2019
234
2142
1423
4634
7886
3143
3243
```

I want to output

```
XXX_2019
3 hours, 54 minutes
1 days, 11 hours, 42 minutes
23 hours, 43 minutes
```

This is not Date time. It's just a minutes column. I am using Vertica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this directly.  Something like this:

```
select trim(leading ', ' from
     (case when XXX_2019 > 24*60 then ', ' || floor(xxx_2019 / (24*60)) || ' days' else '' end) ||
     (case when XXX_2019 > 60 then ', ' || floor((xxx_2019 % (24*60)) / 60) || ' hours' else '' end) ||
     (', ' || xxx_2019 % 60 || ' minutes')
    )
from (values (12345), (123), (12)) v(xxx_2019);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=71fec7de05c432fe983e28514dcadeb1) is a db<>fiddle (using Postgres).

Comment: Thank You ! I tried it but it gave me a syntax error near else so i removed else and then it gave me a syntax error near end.

Comment: I added another ) after end but that didn't help either

Comment: @CHATSHD . . . It works now.  I added a db<>fiddle to verify.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH ! It worked ! but it looks like this -
'2 days, 6 hours, 7.15760803119019 minutes'
Any idea why ?

Comment: @CHATSHD . . . That is strange.  Perhaps `XXX_2019` has a decimal component.  The operator `%` is the modulo operator and returns an integer if both arguments are ints.

Comment: @CHATSHD . . . I'm surprised you unaccepted this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let Vertica do the heavy lifting for you.

Make an interval out of the minute count, then extract day, hour, and minute from the interval and convert them to comma, counter and unit, concatenate all, and remove the initial comma:

```
WITH 
-- your input
input( xxx_2019 ) AS (
          SELECT  234
UNION ALL SELECT 2142
UNION ALL SELECT 1423
UNION ALL SELECT 4634
UNION ALL SELECT 7886
UNION ALL SELECT 3143
UNION ALL SELECT 3243
)
```

-- make an interval out of the minute count

```
,
with_interval AS (
  SELECT 
    xxx_2019 
  , (xxx_2019::char(8)||' minutes')::INTERVAL as dircast
  FROM input
)
```

-- finally, extract the bits from the interval, and format them

```
SELECT 
  dircast
, REGEXP_REPLACE(
      CASE EXTRACT(DAY    FROM dircast) 
        WHEN 0 THEN ''
        ELSE ', '||EXTRACT(DAY  FROM dircast)::VARCHAR(5)||' days'
      END
    || CASE EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM dircast) 
        WHEN 0 THEN ''
        ELSE ', '||EXTRACT(HOUR FROM dircast)::VARCHAR(5)||' hours'
      END
    || CASE EXTRACT(MIN   FROM dircast) 
        WHEN 0 THEN ''
        ELSE ', '||EXTRACT(MIN FROM dircast)::VARCHAR(5)||' minutes'
      END
  , '^, ','') AS s
FROM with_interval
-- out  dircast |              s               
-- out ---------+------------------------------
-- out  03:54   | 3 hours, 54 minutes
-- out  1 11:42 | 1 days, 11 hours, 42 minutes
-- out  23:43   | 23 hours, 43 minutes
-- out  3 05:14 | 3 days, 5 hours, 14 minutes
-- out  5 11:26 | 5 days, 11 hours, 26 minutes
-- out  2 04:23 | 2 days, 4 hours, 23 minutes
-- out  2 06:03 | 2 days, 6 hours, 3 minutes
```

Of course, you can directly, for example:

```
EXTRACT(DAY    FROM (xxx_2019::char(8)||' minutes')::INTERVAL)
```

But I find it much more readable the other way ...

Of course, you can use *@Gordon Linoff* 's approach, but then I'd use the integer division operator in Vertica, the double slash `//`, instead of `FLOOR()`-ing the division afterwards - just to keep within integer arithmetics, which is way faster than floating point arithmetics. And what upsets my pedantic mind is the implicit cast of an INTEGER to character, to then concatenate it with strings ...

```
SELECT
  TRIM(LEADING ', ' FROM
     CASE
       WHEN XXX_2019 > 24*60
       THEN ', ' || ( XXX_2019 // (24*60) )::VARCHAR(5)|| ' days'
       ELSE ''
     END
   ||CASE
       WHEN XXX_2019 > 60
       THEN ', ' || ( (XXX_2019 % (24*60)) // 60 )::VARCHAR(5)|| ' hours'
       ELSE ''
     END
   ||', ' || (xxx_2019 % 60) ::VARCHAR(5)|| ' minutes'
  )                                                                         
FROM input;
```

Comment: Thank you for replying to this thread. I do not understand the first part of your solution as XXX_2019 has many values.

Your modified version of Linoff's approach works well but still gives me some extra values in minutes. Any idea why ?
eg: 
2 days, 6 hours, 7.157 minutes

Comment: Fixed the problem by changing varchar to 2 in minutes for Part 2 of my question